# github actions publish gem package suddenly started to fail

Tags: github, rubygems, github-actions, github-packages

I used to publish gem packages to GitHub Packages using the following GitHub Actions and it was always successful.

```yaml
name: Deploy to Github Packages

on:
  release:
    types:
      - published

env:
  ORGANIZATION: MYGITHUBNAME
  RELEASE_TAG_NAME: ${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Set up JDK 8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 8
          distribution: temurin

      - name: gradlew build
        run: |
          VERSION=$(echo $RELEASE_TAG_NAME | sed -E 's/(v)(.*)/\2/')
          ./gradlew gem -Pversion=$VERSION

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.0

      - name: Setup Release Credentials
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        run: |
          mkdir -p $HOME/.gem
          touch $HOME/.gem/credentials
          chmod 600 $HOME/.gem/credentials
          echo "---" >$HOME/.gem/credentials
          echo ":github: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" >> $HOME/.gem/credentials

      - name: Publish Gem to GitHub Packages
        run: |
          PACKAGE=$(find build/gems -type f | sort | tail -n 1)
          gem push --KEY github --host https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/${ORGANIZATION} ${PACKAGE}`
```

However, with the repository I created today, it suddenly stopped working.
Also, when I create it in an existing repository, it succeeds.

The error message when it fails is:

```
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/MYGITHUBNAME...
Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

When I use PAT to push the gem from my local environment, it succeeds, but it doesn't appear in the "**packages**" of the repository.

If anyone knows what is causing this, please let me know.
Thank you.

- Unified repository and gem names (failed)
- I cloned the repository where `gem push` was successful and tried with a different repository and Gem name (failed)

Comment: Hi! Did you try it with a new PAT with write read/write access to packages?

Comment: thanks Azeem, I tried with the new PAT and I can push it, but it doesn't show up in packages in the repository.
After further investigation, it seems that the link below is affected.
https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-10-packages-fine-grained-permissions-and-organization-level-publishing-are-now-available-for-the-github-packages-rubygems-registry/
Also, since I solved it, I will write down the method.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you could make it work. Lately, I haven't pushed any package to GitHub Packages so I cannot say anything about that. If you already pushed one, you might want to click on that to see that. Maybe, it's under that somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

This was solved!

Apparently, an item called **Workflow permissions** has been added to the repository's `Settings > Actions > General`, and it seems that the existing repository has Read and Write permissions, but the new repository has read-only permissions, hence the permission denied error.

After changing this to Read and Write, I was able to push packages.
If this information is incorrect, could someone please correct it?
Thank you.